# Given path of a unit vector can we derive the rotation matrix?

Tags: matrices, rotations

Let's say a unit vector $\overrightarrow{A}(t)$ in N dimensions is continuously rotated around the origin. It may for example trace out a circle in 3 dimensions or some sort of spiral in higher dimensions.

Can we derive the (infinitessimal) rotation generator $M$ that is rotating the vector over the path $\overrightarrow{A}(t)$? We would have:

$$A(t) = e^{t M } A(0)$$

where $M=-M^T$ is the rotation generator. I wonder if there is a general formula? Perhaps as an infinite series?

Since $M$ has $N(N-1)/2$ components in $N$ dimensions, I suspect that in 3 dimensions one would need at least first and second derivatives of $A(t)$ at a point to work out $M$ and more in higher dimensions.

In 2 dimensions it would be easy. The solution would be

$M=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \theta \\ -\theta & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ with $\theta=\frac{\dot{A}_0(0)}{A_1(0)}=-\frac{\dot{A}_1(0)}{A_0(0)}$

I think in N dimensions you would set up a series of $N(N-1)$ simultaneous equations:

$$\partial^{k+1} A(t) = M \partial^k A(t)$$

for $k=1..N-1$ then you could solve for the components of $M$. Although this gives twice the number of equations we need. If we had $M\subset GL(D)$ this would be easier as the solution would be:

$$ M_{nm} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{D-1}(\partial^{k} A_m(0))^{-1} \partial^{k+1} A_n(0)$$ 
where the inverse is a matrix inverse over the matrix with indices $k$ and $m$.
Not sure how it would change for $M\subset SO(D)$. There would be some identities such as $|A(t)|^2=1$ and all it's derivatives.

**Edit (Clarification due to cases pointed out by John Hughes)**  There will be certain 'degenerate cases' where it is impossible. For example rotating a 3D vector about it's axis traces a point. Let us ignore those cases! (Or on the other hand, find conditions when it is impossible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you define rotation in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as simply an element of $SO(n)$.

$M$ is not unique, unless the image of $A$ spans at least a codimension-1 subspace.  In 2 and 3D, this holds as long as $A'\neq 0$, but in 4D (and hence higher dimensions) you can have $\begin{pmatrix}R_\theta\\&R_\psi\end{pmatrix}$ for any $\psi$ and for $A(0)=e_1$ you only see a rotation in the $e_1,e_2$-plane and know nothing about that is going on in the $e_3,e_4$-plane.

So, let's assume $A(t)$ spans a codimension $\leq 1$ subspace.  We need to solve
$$
A(t)=a_0+e^{it\theta_1}(a_1+ia_2)+e^{-it\theta_2}(a_1-ia_2)+\dots+e^{it\theta_m}(a_{2m-1}+ia_{2m})+e^{-it\theta_m}(a_{2m-1}-ia_{2m})
$$
We have $a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2m}$ are mutually orthogonal, $a_1,\dots,a_{2m}$ are nonzero, and $\theta_1,\dots,\theta_m$ are distinct nonzero, in order for $A(t)$ to span a dimension $2m$ (if $a_0=0$) or $2m+1$ (if $a_0\neq 0$) subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Thus there is a unique linear dependence between $A'(0),A''(0),\dots,A^{(2m+1)}(0)$ (which therefore also works for time $t$).  The coefficients gives you the $\theta_k$ (or rather, $\theta_k^2$), and then looking at kernels give you the $a_k$'s.

---

If you know the Frenet-Serret formula for a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is easier to state the result.  Since $e^{tM}$ is a 1-parameter subgroup of isometries and $A(t)=e^{tM}A(0)$, all generalized curvatures are constant.  So with respect to a Frenet-Serret frame
$$
E_1(t)=\frac{A'(t)}{\lvert-\rvert}, E_2(t)=\frac{E_1'(t)-\dots}{\lvert-\rvert},\dots,E_{2m}=\frac{E_{2m-1}'(t)-\dots}{\lvert-\rvert}
$$
we have
$$
(E_i'(t))=\underbrace{\lvert A'(t)\rvert\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0&-\kappa_1(t)\\
-\kappa_1(t)&0&\ddots\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\kappa_{2m-1}(t)\\
&&-\kappa_{2m-1}(t)&0
\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{constant skew-symmetric matrix}}(E_i(t))
$$
But $E_i(t)$ is just another orthonormal basis if $\{A'(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ spans the whole space.  So just conjugate with a change-of-basis to get $M$.  The extension to $a_0\neq 0$ and codimension-1 is obvious.

Comment: Good answer. I'm trying to get my head round it. BTW do you know of a solution where the matrix $M$ has continuous indices?

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous indices"?  Do you mean your underlying space is a direct integral of Hilbert spaces or something like that?

Comment: Yeah, the vector $A_n$ becomes a function $A(x)$ and the matrix $M_{nm}$ becomes the function $M(x,y)$. It seems like it should be possible... but maybe with a different method.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the vector $e_1 = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0}$ in 4-space, and the rotation
$$
A(t) = \pmatrix{c & -s & 0 & 0 \\
s & c & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1}
$$
where $c = \cos t$ and $s = \sin t$. The vector $e_1$ traces out the unit circle in the $xy$-plane.

Now look at 
$$
B(t) = \pmatrix{c & -s & 0 & 0 \\
s & c & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & c & -s \\
0 & 0 & s & c}
$$
Under the action of $B$, $e_1$ traces out exactly the same path. So from the path, you cannot determine whether you were working with $A(t)$ or $B(t)$.

In three dimensions, if $v$ is the axis of the rotation, you cannot, from the track of $v$, determine the rate of rotation --- not even with multiple derivatives.

Comment: You are correct. Let us assume that there are certain degenerate cases. These seem to occur when the path lies on a sub-plane of the space. For a general 4D curve, I don't think it will trace out a circle in a plane. If we found a formula the degenerate cases would occur when our formula gives 0/0. Your answer is technically correct, but not really the answer I was looking for!

Comment: Then you, informed by my correct answer, need to write a better question, my friend. I think you'll find the examples I gave were in fact representative of quite a general phenomenon.

Comment: I disagree, the examples you gave are special cases (in the sense of picking random matrices) not representative. But I updated my question.

Comment: A general note: Editing a question after someone has given a correct answer is generally a bit rude -- it makes the answer (and answerer) look stupid, which is not the way to treat people who've made an effort on your behalf. That's why I suggested writing a new question.

Comment: That's why I wrote EDIT in big black writing. If I asked "Can I find x where $ax+b=0$?" and someone wrote, "No because a might be zero, hence $x$ is can be arbitary." Then I would consider this answer, although technically correct, not a full answer as it didn't give the case that in most cases we can solve it for $x=-b/a$.